# Missing ionic.project file

Tags: ionic-framework

I just updated nodejs ionic and cordova. Create new ionic project as before:

```
ionic start myApp blank
```

In terminal, go to myApp directory, and input:

```
ionic state
```

I got message:

> You cannot run any state commands on a project that is not an Ionic
>   project. Try adding an ionic.project file or running ionic start to
>   get an application to save or restore (CLI v1.7.10)

My system information:

- Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
- Ionic Version: 1.1.1
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.3
- ios-sim version: 5.0.4
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v5.1.0
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005

Question: Where ionic.project file, I don't remember there was this file in project before. How to add ionic.project file?

How do I find this problem? Because I check out source from git, I try to use ionic state restore command to restore application for building. But I got same message, missing ioinc.project. So I create a new ionic project to find reason, but I'm still confused.

If use

```
ionic start
```

You will got

> Invalid command (CLI v1.7.10)

Of course, there is not directory argument for this command. If you give directory as ./, this command only create and overwrite all project file.

screen shot
[image]

Comment: Did you type this command from project directory?[Move to project directory cd myApp command]?

Comment: @Muhsin yes, I input ionic command in project directory. cd myApp before input ionic state.

Comment: Could you please share  screen shot of your project structure and terminal?

Comment: @Muhsin add screen shot

Comment: :Lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95769/ionic-installation-problem

Comment: Pleae  remove the ionic npm module and reinstall it[
npm uninstall -g ionic,
npm install -g ionic]

Comment: @Muhsin reinstall module is unuseful. Which version are you using? And do you have ionic.project file? ionic state command works fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96101/discussion-between-muhsin-and-gino).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.
just run the command

ionic serve

ionic.project file gets auto generated

**EDIT**

ionic.project is replace by ionic.config.json. So you should change in ionic.config.json

Comment: Your answer is no longer valid it was renabmed please see below.

Answer (score 32):

The new name of this file is ionic.config.json

Answer (score 0):

If you are happened to use ionic@beta, it won't install it until you downgrade it to ionic V1 then "ionic setup sass" or "ionic serve".

Answer (score 0):

Most simple/easy solution to this problem to install a chrome extension named CORS. and everything will work perfectly.